# Camera Option Change

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am coding with Swift to develop a Video Camera App. In order to do it, I am using UiimagePickercontroller. But since the key feature of my app is a video camera but a photo camera, I would like to switch the order of "Photo" and "Video" on my app. But when it runs, the "Photo" is always selected first. I just want the "Video" to be selected first, and then if users want to use the "Photo", they swipe to change it. See the screenshot below.

[Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRcZv.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the key feature of your app is video camera then present only video camera, why you present both. If you do below you will get only video camera:

```
    let imagepickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagepickerController.sourceType = .camera
    imagepickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
    imagepickerController.delegate = self
    self.present(imagepickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you include "public.image" in the imagepickerController.mediaTypes then it will give system default controls by default selecting photo and this seems to be non-configurable.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I guess that some users also want to use the "Phots". So my understanding is that there is no way to switch the orders of the two options, right?

Comment: Yes, I think so because it is system default provided controls and i don't see any properties to configure that. I think if you want to provide both then you can provide 2 different controllers one with only video and one with only image as a 2 separate buttons.